# Weird behavior when setting a row's height on EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-5, epplus

I am building an Excel file with EEPlus under MVC-5 C# application. Everything goes as planned until I set a height on a row (so an image can fit).

I load de images and set the height on column 20, like so:

```
Image cfPhoto = null;
Bitmap cfBm = null;
ExcelPicture pictureCf = null;
var photoInitialColumn = 0;
i++;
completedFormPhotos.ForEach(delegate(CompletedFormPhoto cfP)
{
    cfPhoto = Image.FromFile(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/FormPhotos/" + cfP.Id + ".jpg"));
    cfBm = new Bitmap(cfPhoto, new Size(215, 170));
    pictureCf = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture(cfP.Id.ToString(), cfBm);
    pictureCf.SetPosition(i+1, 0, photoInitialColumn, 10);
    worksheet.Cells[_alpha[photoInitialColumn] + (i + 3) + ':' + _alpha[photoInitialColumn + 1] + (i + 3)].Merge = true;
    worksheet.Cells[_alpha[photoInitialColumn] + (i + 3) + ':' + _alpha[photoInitialColumn + 1] + (i + 3)].Value = cfP.comment;
    worksheet.Cells[_alpha[photoInitialColumn] + (i + 3) + ':' + _alpha[photoInitialColumn + 1] + (i + 3)].Style.WrapText = true;
    photoInitialColumn += 2;
    //HERE I SET THE HEIGHT. At this point, i == 18 
    worksheet.Row(i+2).Height = 180;
});
```

But, I have a company logo at the top of the Excel file (A1 cell) which gets resized as well (on height). That is defined like this:

```
Image _keyLogo = Image.FromFile(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/key_logo.png"));
var pictureLogo = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Logo Key Quimica", _keyLogo);
pictureLogo.SetPosition(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Resulting on this:

[image: Screenshot of the Excel File]

Any help would be really appreciated.

[Here](http://eduardoibarra.com/dl/myfilename(18).xlsx) is the excel file in question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It comes down to the `EditAs` setting of the picture logo. By default it will be set to `OneCell` but setting it to `TwoCell` I believe will solve your problem.  The documentation on it (looking at EPP 4.0.1) is rather cryptic but it basically says this setting will tell the drawing to maintain its original row/column position and size.  The names seem a bit counter intuitive though.

I had to guess what your code looks like (let me know if I got it wrong) and I was able to reproduce the problem you were having and then solve with the `EditAs` setting:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Image_Stretch_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873762/weird-behavior-when-setting-a-rows-height-on-epplus
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("newsheet");

        var _keyLogo = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Ernie/Desktop/key_logo.png");
        var pictureLogo = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Logo Key Quimica", _keyLogo);
        pictureLogo.SetPosition(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pictureLogo.EditAs = eEditAs.TwoCell;  //REMOVE THIS TO SHOW THE STRETCH PROBLEM

        var cfPhoto = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Ernie/Desktop/Main_Pic.png");
        var cfBm = new Bitmap(cfPhoto, new Size(215, 170));

        var pictureCf = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Main_Pic", cfBm);
        pictureCf.SetPosition(10, 0, 0, 0);

        worksheet.Row(11).Height = 280;

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

The other thing that fix it was add the logo AFTER the row resize but not sure if that is practical to what you are trying to do.

Comment: This did the trick even when calling .SetSize(w, h) - if EditAs was left with the default value, the image would have been stretched to a square the size of the lesser of the parameters to SetSize.

Comment: what is eEditAs.TwoCell;  ? i found no where defined eEditAs....what it is ? is it row or cell instance ? please guide me. thanks