# Centering, Merging, and Wrapping Text In Cells - EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, epplus

I'm trying to center a header(s) for an excel file like so:
[image: Excel Table]

But I am missing a few details, since the code below one writes on one line and does not expand the cell's height. Here is my code so far:

```
ws.Cells[$"A{row}:F{row}"].Merge = true;
ws.Cells[$"A{row}"].Style.WrapText = true;
ws.SelectedRange[$"A{row}"].Value = purchaseHistory[0].LineText;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To center the merged cell both vertical and horizontally just do this:

```
//Only need to grab the first cell of the merged range
ws.Cells[$"A{row}"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
ws.Cells[$"A{row}"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

If you need to do something with the height of the rows you will want to look at the `CustomHeight` setting.  This should explain it:  [Autofit rows in EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496172/autofit-rows-in-epplus)