# Change Code From Microsoft Interop To EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, image, epplus

I have created a set of code to export images from my Image folder into Excel using Microsoft Interop, now I want to change my codes from Microsoft Interop to [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Can someone help me with this?

This is my codes:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

    string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Image"));
    int count = 0;
    foreach (string img in filesindirectory)
    {
        count++;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Add();
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image TEST_IMAGE = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        worksheet.Name = "Title- " + count;
        TEST_IMAGE.ImageUrl = "Image/" + Path.GetFileName(img);
        TEST_IMAGE.ImageUrl = this.GetAbsoluteUrl(TEST_IMAGE.ImageUrl);
        worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(TEST_IMAGE.ImageUrl, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 300);
    }
    workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Delete();
    workbook.Worksheets["Sheet2"].Delete();
    workbook.Worksheets["Sheet3"].Delete();
    workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    app.Quit();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To read an image into excel via epplus you can use this as an example (it will also show you how to setup a new workbook from scratch):

[Weird behavior when setting a row's height on EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873762/weird-behavior-when-setting-a-rows-height-on-epplus/27893500#27893500)

To delete a worksheet you can do that like this:

```
using (var pack = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    var ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet1");
    pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(ws);
    ...
}
```

But if you are just trying to clean out the default sheets created by excel when you create a new file you DONT need to do that with EPPlus - by default there are no sheet when creating a new `package` (i.e. workbook).  It is up to the programmer to add sheets and it will throw an error if there is not at least one.